# Data Preparation for Count Modeling with glm

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution, poisson-regression

I'm modeling claim count using glm. 
My data contains **both continuous and categorical data**.
Data is aggregated to **6000 risk profiles**(referenced here by **ID**). **Exposure** for a policyholder for 1 year

[image]

Here a summary of all columns:
[image]

In fact, As far as I know, I must probably **convert my continuous variables to categorical**, is that all I have to do?
I'll be modeling my glm using first **Poisson and N.B type 2**, I also think I might use **exposure as an offset**? 
Also, should **ID** and **Year**, stay as an explanatory variable?

Comment: you need to look at the data before deciding whether to convert it to categorical. It's not a must. also some of your columns, e.g Rent are character.. hope that is intended. ID is a unique entry, you cannot use it

Comment: thanks for your comment, but if they are caracters, must it be converted to numbers or ligical when its 2 choices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, transfomring categorical to dummy variable may not help you in the end.

https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat504/node/169/

This article shows specific steps about poisson regression modelling process in considering overdispersion and engineering variables.

Using offset may help to address over-dispersion, the article is worth a good read, after using offset, the model appearted to be good fit.

Regards,
Dan